# Crash in NRMANSURLConnectionSupport

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I Keep getting the following crash log in my new relic board. But I am not able to replicate the bug. The issue affects maybe more than half of the users. Has anyone else faced a similar issue or know how to fix it?

```html
Hardware Model:      iPhone 6 (iPhone7,2)
Process:         T_APP [1421]
Code Type:       arm64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-07-22 01:09:04 +0000
Launch Time:     2015-07-22 01:09:04 +0000
OS Version:      iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Crashed Thread:  14

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SIGSEGV', reason: ''

Thread 14 Crashed:
0   CFNetwork                     0x187e41030 __ZN11HTTPMessage20ensureParserFinishedEv + 69680
1   CFNetwork                     0x187e40fb8 __ZN11HTTPMessage19copyAllHeaderFieldsEPPK9__CFArray + 69560
2   CFNetwork                     0x187e766d4 [NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields] + 288468
3   T_App                         0x10006b22c [NRMANSURLConnectionSupport noticeResponse:forRequest:withTimer:andBody:bytesSent:bytesReceived:] (NRMANSURLConnectionSupport.m:341)
4   T_App                         0x100097fe0 [NRMANSURLConnectionDelegateBase connectionDidFinishLoading:] (NRMANSURLConnectionDelegateBase.m:126)
5   CFNetwork                     0x187f8ae70 ___65-[NSURLConnectionInternal + 1420912
6   CFNetwork                     0x187f8ae00 [NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 1420800
7   CFNetwork                     0x187f8af7c [NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 1421180
8   CFNetwork                     0x187f2c3f4 ____ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic23_delegate_cacheTrifectaEPK20_CFCachedURLResponseU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 1033204
9   CFNetwork                     0x187f28540 ____ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 1017152
10  CFNetwork                     0x187e4bb54 __ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 113492
11  CoreFoundation                0x1883c8aac _CFArrayApplyFunction + 35500
12  CFNetwork                     0x187e4ba00 __ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 113152
13  CFNetwork                     0x187e4b8b4 __ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 112820
14  CFNetwork                     0x187e4b6e0 __ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 112352
15  CoreFoundation                0x18849e9ec ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 911852
16  CoreFoundation                0x18849dc90 ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 908432
17  CoreFoundation                0x18849bd40 ___CFRunLoopRun + 900416
18  CoreFoundation                0x1883c90a4 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 37028
19  WebCore                       0x195f50674 __ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 935540
20  JavaScriptCore                0x189950b80 __ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 84864
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19945fe80 __pthread_body + 16000
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19945fddc __pthread_body + 15836
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x19945cfb0 _thread_start + 4016
```

Comment: It looks like an unexpected headerfield is the problem. Can you post a code sample of how you're parsing headers in your NSURLConnections?